# A difficulty in understanding Proposition 10. in Dummit & Foot p.195

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

The book states that:"Let G and K be groups, let H be a subgroup of G and let $\phi : G \rightarrow K$ be a surjective homomorphism.

(2)$\phi(G^{(i)}) = K^{(i)}.$ In particular, homomorhpic images and quotient groups of solvable groups are solvable (of solvable length $\leq$ to that of the domain group)

(3) If N is normal in G and both N and G/N are solvable then so is G."

The proof of (3) of the book is as follows: Finally, if G/N and N are solvable, of lengths n and m respectively then by (2) applied to the natural projection $\phi : G \rightarrow G/N$ we obtain $$\phi(G^{(n)}) = (G/N)^{(n)} = 1N$$

i.e., $G^{(n)}\leq N.$

And then the book completes the proof.

-But, I did not understand in the statement of the proof in (2) this statement "(of solvable length $\leq$ to that of the domain group)" I need an example that shows this. Could anyone explain this for me please?

-Also, I did not understand in the proof of (3), How $\phi(G^{(n)}) = (G/N)^{(n)} = 1N$ means  $G^{(n)}\leq N.$  Could anyone explain this for me please?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solvable means that $G^{(n)}=\{1\}$ for some $n$.  The solvable length is the minimal $n$ that satisfies that, let me represent it with a capital $N$.  So, if $\phi(G^{(n)})=\phi(G)^{(n)}$ for all $n$, then in particular $\phi(G)^{(N)}=\phi(G^{(N)})=\phi(\{1\})=\{1\}$, so $\phi(G)$ is solvable with solvable length $\leq N$.  Note that in the statement, since $\phi$ is surjective, $K=\phi(G)$.

For the second part, where $\phi$ is the projection, the fact that the map takes every element of $G^{(n)}$ to the identity in the image means that every element of $G^{(n)}$ is in the kernel of $\phi$, ie. $N$.

Comment: I  need an example of a solvable group of length n that contains a solvable subgroup of length m where m< n ?

Comment: I did not understand why $\phi(G^{(n)}) = (G/N)^{(n)} = 1N$ leads to   $G^{(n)}$ is a subgroup of  N.

Comment: Take any solvable group of length $n$. It's commutator subgroup is solvable of length $n-1$.   The map $\phi$ takes an element of $G$ to its coset in $G/N$. To be in the coset $1N$ means to be in $N$. So $\phi(G^{(n)})=1N$ means every element of $G^{(n)}$ is in $N$